# Will the alert show this message in flex or flash builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a colleague who will be using Adobe Flex and adobe flash builder to design the application. The final application will be in that software. I am creating the database features and testing them using online browsers.

What I want to know is that some alerts I am getting a 'prevent this message from multiple dialogues' message on the alert but this is because of the browsers. But if the application is on flex and flash builder (I don't know which one is where the app is stored coz I have never used it) then will that message appear on some alerts in that software or is it only on browsers?

Below is javascript code which contains alert:

```
         function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        alert("Your Details for this Session has been submitted");
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is considered a "Best Practice" to edit your question to add more details; not to delete the old question and re-post it.  Flex will not fire a JavaScript dialog unless explicitly programmed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, no, the alert will only come into play when testing directly via the browser with your javascript function.

Besides, I assume you will be submitting the data directly via the flex / flash application, and this is simply for testing your script to handle the submitted data.

On a side note, you don't need to call .submit() within your function as your ajax $.post is already submitting the form data.

Comment: I have the submit() function because I want to post the data on a seperate page but I want the user to stay on the same page it is on, not to navigate to the 'insertQuestion.php'. So just to clarify you are saying that the 'prevent this message...' sentence would not appear on the alert if the application is on a flash application? The alert though would come up in flash builder if this code is inserted in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Note (just so you know), in Flex there is an `Alert` class that functions similar to the Javascript `alert` function.

If your Flex application makes use of the Flex `Alert` class, you will never see that message about multiple dialogs, b/c the browser won't be generating the alert.

However, it is possible to call Javascript functions within Flash (see `ExternalInterface`). So if you triggered the Javascript `alert` function from Flash, the browser will show the alert dialog and potentially the text about multiple dialogs.

Hope that makes sense, and helps!